# XCode 4 How to debug without disassemblies

Tags: xcode, debugging, disassembly

I searched already 30 minutes and I do not find the answer.
I am debuggin in XCode 4.3 and when I step through my code, I always get into code where I do not have the source code, so I will see the disassembly. How can I stop this. I just want to step through my own code.

I found some answers for Xcode 3, where you could change it in Run -> Debug -> Source Code Only or Source Code and Disassembly.

But where can I find this in XCode 4?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am also searching for this in Xcode 4. I also just got a crash and I don't see a stack track - only UIApplication!

Comment: On a related note - for OS X, Apple has a nice list of debugging tricks in general: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Checkout the slider at the bottom of the debug window (Navigate -> Reveal in Debug Navigator). The slider is adjoined by an "=" on the left (Compress the thread list) and one on the right (Decompress the thread list).  Tap the one on the right to show the entire stack.

Here's a link of more information (scroll down to "Examining Threads and Stacks"
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under **Product->Debug Workflow->Show Disassembly when debugging**